# How do you find the date when one column stopped equaling another column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following variables in a dataset:

UserID  |  Date | Workplace | First_Workplace

Users are assigned to a workplace (Remote or Office). I'm trying to figure out when each user returned to the office and Workplace no longer equaled First_Workplace. I need to add this data to a new column named Date_Changed.

Sudo code would be something like the below. I just can't figure it out in R:

```
data %>%
  mutate(data, Date_Changed = Date WHEN Workplace != First_Workplace FOR EACH UserID)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `which` on the logical values to get the index and select the first index with `[1]`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(UserID) %>%
   mutate(Date_changed = Date[which(Workplace != 
              first(Workplace))[1]]) %>%
   ungroup
```

NOTE: If there is no change, it returns `NA`

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(UserID = rep(1:3, each = 3),
  Workplace = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C"),
   Date = Sys.Date() + 0:8)
```